# IQKeyboardManager not working when UITableView embedded in a container view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicontainerview, iqkeyboardmanager

Currently, I am working with a container view with an embedded `UITableView` and am using the `IQKeyboardManager` CocoaPod to scroll the view so my `UITextFields` and `UITextViews` are not covered by the keyboard.

I can successfully `import IQkeyboardManager` and make it work in other views but it's not working when the `UITableView` is embedded in a container view.

Comment: I've clarified your question but there's still not nearly enough information to help. Show the entire code of the class that's doing this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES]; // This line is needed for the 'auto slide up'
   // Do other stuff
}
```

Simple solution , No need to create observer.

Comment: Great ! , saved my day !

Comment: Thanks - I'm using this now too. Out of curiousity - does this work because it ensures the IQKeyboardManager classes are executed before the ones in the viewcontroller?

Comment: So much hassle for one line of code, I spent at least 4 hours until figuring out this was what I was missing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried this solution with latest IQKeyboardManagerSwift  (4.0.10) and it didn't work.

Comment: Awesome answer...saved my day...kudos

Answer (score 10):

I've had a similar issue and fixed it using the info given [here](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/issues/285) from the author of the library.

The key statement is:

> library logic is to find nearest scrollView from textField. and in your case it's tableView, that is why library chooses tableView to scroll.

So the solution I've used is to disable the UITableView scroll property when the textfield/view is being edited (use the delegate methods), and then re-enable it once editing has finished. This ensures that the library does not detect the UITableView as scrollable and so it ignores it and then moves your container view instead - as you intended. Once the view has moved up as you wanted it to, you can re-enable scrolling via the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification.

So for example, for the UITextField:

```
-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:NO];
}

- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:YES];
}
```

However to still allow scrolling after the view has moved up, I have registered for the keyboard notification and then allowed scrolling once the keyboard is up:

```
-(void) keyboardWillShow {
    [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:YES];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];

}
```

Comment: Your solution seems very logical, but it doesn't work for me even if I make the tableview not scrollable in viewDidLoad() .. do you have any idea why that happens?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ vivek agravat Answer!
Here's the swift version:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
          super.viewWillAppear(true)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try to scroll all your view

in viewDidLoad

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourVC.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourVC.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

and after

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification)
    {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue()
        {
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification:NSNotification)
    {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue()
        {
            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
```

you can change `keyboardSize`

Comment: You misunderstood the question. He's using a CocoaPod to handle the scrolling, and it's not the entire view that should move here -- the tableview should scroll.